# C++ pointer to a class member in the same class [Conceptual]?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

`

```
class A{
public:
    int x;
    A* p;
};

int main(){

    A obj1 = new A(); //no suitable constructor exists to convert from "A *" to "A"
    A *obj2 = new A(); //Works fine
    return 0;
}
```

`

Why is an object of class A declared as a pointer to that class, by default?

In other words, why does obj1 doesn't work but *obj2 does.

Comment: Well, you 're using `new`.

Comment: `obj` is not a pointer to class A.

Comment: you should not try to write C++ as you write java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new` operator returns a pointer, so you can assign it only to a variable of pointer type.

You can use `A obj1 = A();`, which will simply call the constructor (without allocating dynamic memory, which is what `new` does) and return a `A`, not a `A*`.

Answer (score 1):

No. `Why is an object of class A declared as a pointer to that class, by default?` Is incorrect. An object of class is just an object of that type and no pointer there.

The keyword `new` is used to allocate dynamic memory for a pointer. That is a memory must be cleaned up manually when you're done with it otherwise you will face a memory leak.

```
A* pObj = new A; // ok
A  obj = new A; // error
A  obj = *pObj; // ok:
```

Above `obj` is just an instance of class A and pObj is a pointer to an object of class A so inside the pointer there's the address of the object so to access it we `dereference` the pointer:

```
obj = *pObj = 0; // De-referencing pObj and assigning the value it points to to obj.
```

Finally clean up:

```
delete pObj; // ok
delete obj; // error
```